# Return lists that do not have 1s

Tags: python, list

I want to create what I thought was a fairly straightforward function.  The function just runs through a list of lists and returns any list that does not have a `1` in all of the list elements following the second `element ([2: ])`.  So given the list of lists `[[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2, 0.3, 1, 1, 1]]` the function would return `[4, 5, 1, 2, 0.3, 1, 1, 1]`.  What I have so far is:

```
 def discover(A):
    """Looks for list that has an element not equal to one.
    """
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            if A[i][j+2] != 1:
                print A[i]
```

But when I run the function it finds one list but then prints that list over and over again before giving me an IndexError saying the list index is out of range.  This seems to be a fairly easy problem but for some reason I'm not getting it.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
for j in range(len(A[i])):
  if A[i][j+2] != 1:
```

What'll happen is that you'll eventually get to a point where `j` is the length of your list, minus 1. But then you're calling `j+2` in the below code, and that's guaranteed to create a number longer than your list, giving you the `IndexError`. You can fix that with:

```
for j in range(2,len(A[i])):
  if A[i][j] != 1:
```

As for the endless printing, you're nearly there, but you'll want to stop the loop if you find the non-1 element.

```
if A[i][j] != 1:
  print A[i]
  break
```

Alternately, the other answers will give you the same result more easily. But that's where your current errors are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

A query to check if any element (after the second) != 1 would be:

`any(x != 1 for x in mylist[3:])`

so

```
def discover(A):
    for mylist in A:
        if any(x != 1 for x in mylist[3:]):
            print mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for list in A:
     if 1 not in list[3:]:
          print list
```

Answer (score 0):

even another solution:

```
lst = [
 [1,2,3],
 [1,1,1],
 [3,4,5],
 [3,5,6],
] # +++

def has1(subLst):
    return subLst.count(1) == 0

print filter(has1, lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoids out of range issues.

```
def discover(A):
    results = []
    for lst in A:
        for i in lst[3:]:
            if i != 1:
                results.append(lst)
                break
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here, one could also make use of a generator. The `yield` statement will allow you to skirt establishing a default list to place your results into; you can just specify the condition you're looking for and `yield` the result.

```
>>> def discover(lists):
...     for l in lists:
...             if not [x for x in l[2:] if x != 1]:
...                     yield l
>>> stuff = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> results = discover(stuff) #returns  <generator object discover at 0x105e3eb90>
>>> results.next()
[2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

The magic line here being, `if not [x for x in l[2:] if x !=1]`. It builds a list from `l[2:]` and checks that any variable in there does not equal 1; if the list has no length, it means there are no non-1 entries in `l[2:]` and so it yields `l`.